# How can I show a comment block inside a code block inside a doxygen block?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Let's say I want to show a `/* - */` delimited comment block inside a code block in a
Doxygen documentation block in C++ code.  If the Doxygen block, is itself `/* - */`
delimited, like this,

```
/**
    documentation
    \code
    /*
        comment 
    */
    \endcode
*/
```

that's clearly going to be a problem: Doxygen will do the right thing, but a C++ compiler
won't know that it should ignore the inner `*/`.  An alternative is to use a
`///`-delimited Doxygen block:

```
/// documentation
/// \code
/// /*
///     comment 
/// */
/// \endcode
```

This version won't confuse the C++ compiler, but now Doxygen adds an extra star.  How can I make both Doxygen and C++ happy?

[image: doxygen html output]

---

It was suggested in comments that I could at least align the extra asterisk with the ones that are supposed to be there, making the output look better. In some cases that might be acceptable, but I think that would be a problem for me, so let me explain why.  The documentation is discussing a renderer shading language that understands `#include` and single-line comments but not block comments, and wants to say:

> Block comment lines are not supported, but may not matter if the included file does not close the block:
>
> ```
> /*
>   #include "MyFile.h" --> file will be included anyway.
> */
> ```

If that gets changed to

> ```
> /*
>  *  #include "MyFile.h" --> file will be included anyway.
>  */
> ```

then it may *look* fine, but I don't know if it will be semantically correct any more, because I don't know what that extra asterisk would do.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @albert doxygen version 1.9.3 (the latest I can install using homebrew)

Comment: Results for the current version (1.9.4 (5d15657a55555e6181a7830a5c723af75e7577e2)) will be the same. To answer the question probably the best is to add the `*` yourself in the `///` version before the word `comment`.

Comment: @albert I don't get it, why would I add a star when I want to get rid of a star?

Comment: When you add a star so it looks like `///  * comment`, the result would be nicely aligned.

Comment: I did some investigations and although the name might be a bit misleading maybe the setting `MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF=YES` can help you (it works for the small case presented).

Comment: What about the other way round? Line comments within a doxygen block comment?

Comment: @albert I'm working within a large open-source project, and I think a global configuration change like that would be too disruptive.

Comment: As a side note A question for me is: "are the `/*` and `*/` necessary"?

Comment: You wrote: "I'm working within a large open-source project" which project? where is its code available?

Comment: @albert This is for [Ogre-Next](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre-next).  I'm trying to correct doxygen errors in documentation that someone else wrote.

Comment: @JWWalker thanks, I thought so. Very good and noble thing that you try to update the docs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is not possible to have a code block in a comment and I suggested to maybe use the `\snippet` command I give an example of it usage here:

```
/// documentation
/// \snippet this S1
void fie();

// [S1]
 /*
  comment
  */
// [S1]
```

resulting in:

[image]

Note: you can also use e.g.:

```
/// documentation
/// \snippet this S1
// [S1]
 /*
  comment
  */
// [S1]
void fie();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do the *opposite*.

My docs use `/** ... */` and comments within code blocks use `//`:

```
/** \brief My doc
 *
 * \code
 *     // this is a comment
 *     here is some code...
 * \endcode
 */
```

I'm not aware of a way to add C-like comments here. Note that most C compilers now support the C++ comment syntax too.